# Establishing MySql connection in Windows Service

Tags: c#, mysql, windows-services, connection-string

I am using C# in Visual Studio 2015. I wrote a windows form application that creates an object and serializes it. The object contains information that can be used to construct MySQL select commands. All of that works well.

Now I am writing a Windows Service to use those objects to monitor a MySQL database. I have been able to get the windows service installed and running on my computer, so I know that works fine.

I'm able to connect to MySQL with the windows service so that it can monitor the database. Right now, I am using this code in the OnStart method:

```
try{
    string connectionString = @"server=my_server;database=my_database;userid=my_username;password=my_password;";
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    conn.Open()
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //Log error
}
```

The problem is that this program is going to be used on multiple databases so the password in the connection string will need to change. I can easily save the connection string to the serialized object but I have no idea what the proper way is to securely get a password. Is there a different, better method for connecting to MySQL from a windows service? I am new to windows services so I'm sorry if I'm missing something simple.

[EDIT]

One thing I did consider was sending a SecureString from the Windows Form Application to the Windows Service (which is something I don't know how to do yet) then using that in the windows service to connect. The only problem I can see with that method is that if the service ever shuts down, then those passwords are lost and would need to be re-entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encrypt the connection string in the app.config. Have a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx

But that way you cannot edit the config manually as it would look like this:

```
<connectionStrings configProtectionProvider="DataProtectionConfigurationProvider">
  <EncryptedData>
    <CipherData>
      <CipherValue>AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE/Cl+sBAAAAH2... </CipherValue>
    </CipherData>
  </EncryptedData>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for.